# "client.get_historical_klines" from Binance API doesn't return good value

Tags: python-3.x, binance-api-client

Using the function below gives me this result:

> [1637971200000, '53756.29000000', '53859.31000000', '53747.77000000', '53853.57000000', '16.49892000', 1637971259999, '887949.68081540', 639, '12.00163000', '645905.65329110', '0']

```
client.get_historical_klines("BTCBUSD", Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE, "27 Nov, 2021 00:00:00","27 Nov, 2021 00:00:59")
```

If I compare with the graph at the same date, candle doesn't match.

[BTCBUSD Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgm5V.png)

Where did I go wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are looking at the wrong candle. Your picture reveals that you are in UTC+1, so you have to look at 01:00 to see the correct handle

Comment: Well seen friend ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `testnet` to **False** in `binance.Client(api_key, secret_key, testnet)`

Answer (score 0):

frame = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines(symbol, interval, lookback + " day ago UTC"))

Comment: Could you explain why this code snippet works...?